ASP.NET MVC rotativa iss blank page problem
I create PDF files with rotativa in ASP.NET MVC.
It works fine on localhost, but when I publish it on the web via iss, the pdf shows a blank page.
I copied the relevant dll files to the Rotativa folder
msvcr120.dll
msvcp140.dll
msvcp120.dll


I downloaded the latest version from https://wkhtmltopdf.org/
I gave all permissions to the folders
I tried all the methods in the forums

I couldn't solve the problem - I'm waiting for your help.
enter image description here
enter image description here
public ActionResult PrintSalarySlip(int id)
{
    // PDF oluşturulacak sayfanın adı ve parametrelerle birlikte ayarlandı
    var pdfResult = new ActionAsPdf("IndexById", new { id = id })
        {
            PageOrientation = Orientation.Portrait,
            PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4,
            CustomSwitches = "--load-error-handling ignore" // Hata yönetimi için opsiyonel
        };

    // PDF'yi indirme olarak sunmak için bir dosya adı belirleyin
    var pdfFile = pdfResult.BuildFile(ControllerContext);
    
    // PDF dosyasını indirme olarak sunmak
    return File(pdfFile, "application/pdf", "SalarySlip.pdf");
}

View
@Html.ActionLink("Göster", "PrintSalarySlip", new { id = item.P_S_ID, @class = "btn btn-info" })


Hi, I could not solve the problem with Rotativa. I updated my codes with itextsharp and it works fine now.Thank you for your support
